# Link author name to author profile page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I've author profile set up separately, and I'm printing author name outside of loop using strlen to limit the long names but unable to get the link attached to author name.. It just prints the author name without link in it.. Your help will be highly appreciated..

I tried with this one, which simply output the author name without link..

```
echo strlen(get_the_author_link()) > 13 ? substr(get_the_author_link(),0,12).'..' : get_the_author_link();
```

Comment: Are you able to show more of your code so we can see where the data is coming from and what it looks like?

Comment: @DaveCooper The above code is working both in and outside loop but they are not able to generate link.. strlen (get_the author_link()) just strips the author link even within loop..When I just call - get_the author_link(); it normally works without any problem.. I'm really not aware whether strlen strips any link attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for get_the_author_link (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link), says that the function returns the link to the authors website. This link is an html link. It has a text and a href attribute.

The text of this link is the name of the author. The href attribute of this link is the link to the author's website. The substr function that you are using extracts the first 12 characters of this link so it will return a portion of the link's html.

If you want to shorten the author's name then you can shorten the text of the link. Another option is to display the authors link with a small font using css